# Calling setExposedInput() from a Drush command doesn't have any effect

Tags: views, webforms, drush

We have a custom Drush command implemented using the following code.

```php
class JobApplicationExportCommands extends DrushCommands {

  /**
   * Exports Dorea Job Applications since the last run to csv
   *
   * @command dummy:job-application-export
   * @aliases duje
   */
  public function drush_dummy_export() {
    $applicationWebformIds = Drupal::entityQuery('webform')
      ->condition('category', 'Bewerbungsformulare')
      ->execute();

    $applicationView = Views::getView('all_applications');
    $applicationView->setDisplay('default');
    $applicationView->setExposedInput([
      'webform_ids' => array_keys($applicationWebformIds),
      'submitted' => '2021-01-01'
    ]);

    $applicationView->execute();

    // This outputs 0, which is wrong.
    print_r(count($applicationView->result));
  }

}
```

The view configuration is the following.

> [image: screenshot]

If I execute the same logic via a custom controller / normal request, the view does return values.

Am I missing something? Does anybody know why the exposed input of the view is ignored?

Comment: Just a thought: perhaps contextual filter could work instead?

Comment: thx, I'll check that :)

Comment: I once had a weird issue where `setExposedInput` was only working when `use ajax` was enabled in views advanced settings. Not sure why and if it helps here, but worth trying.

Comment: The funny thing is, that even if I  drop the exposed input. and go via the more hardcoded approach of `hook_views_query_alter` I get 0 results via drush

Comment: also neither enabling ajax nore using contextual filters changed the unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Uh! I think it has something to do with the user - if I'm not logged in as admin, I also get 0 results via the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, a colleague saved me again: The access checks can be dissabled individually per view via Query settings > Disable SQL rewriting

[image]

For this particular view and usecase this is exactly what is needed, as it is only callable by backend processes.